# Automorphism groups of $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_4$

Tags: group-theory

I need to show that the order of $Aut(\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_4)$ is 96.

I do know that the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb Z_p^n$ is $GL_n(\mathbb F_p)$, but well, in my case 4 isn't prime..

I am guessing though, that I need to find some kind of a map $Aut(\mathbb Z_4^2)\rightarrow M_2(\mathbb Z_4)$, but I don't really know how to use it to find the order, and I don't know how to define the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed as in the usual solution of finding automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$, where $p$ is a prime.

Automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ correspond naturally to invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z}_4$. A matrix with entries in a commutative ring (with unit) is invertible if and only if its determinant is invertible. So with this approach, you should prove that the number of solutions to $ad - bc = \pm 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is exactly $96$.

Comment: $(4^2 - 2^2)(4^2- 2\cdot 4)$ is the corresponding expression from $(q^2-1)(q^2-q)$ that you get by considering bases. If $q=p^2$, then you get $(q^2-p^2)(q^2-pq)=(p^4-p^2)(p^4-p^3)$.

Comment: @JackSchmidt I am unable to udnerstand your logic. Can you please provide me some link from where I can get the concept of your answer ? Like I mean how did you find out $(q^2-p^2)(q^2-pq)$ ? Is there any special formula in general ?

Comment: @spin Will your process work in general for $\mathbb Z_{p^m}^n$ where $p$ is prime ?